# Adjust width of Grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, resize

I have searched, with no success, for an answer to this issue. I have created a UITableView using the `Grouped` style. It is a landscape app for the iPad and I only want the table on the left (in the area 0, 300, 20, 748), however setting the `tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 300, 748)` does nothing.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sections;


@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize sections = _sections;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 300, 748) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 300, 748);

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [tableView reloadData];

    NSArray *first = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first", @"second", @"third", nil];
    NSArray *second = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fourth", @"fifth", @"sixth", nil];

    self.sections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first, second, nil];

    self.view = tableView;

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.sections count];
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.sections objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.sections objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 300, 748);

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I'm looking for a way to resize the table so that it is only 300 pixels wide and on the left.  Any suggestions on how this is possible?

Comment: Have you checked the `autoresizingMask` property on your table view? See what it is defaulted to. Also, you might want to check the frame/autoresizingMask property on `ViewController`. It's possible that your containing view is filling the landscape frame, and your table view is following suit.

Comment: Does your `ViewController` (bad name BTW) extend `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`?

Comment: yeah it was a test class i just made (hence the name) and thanks for all the quick replies, i have sorted it out though thank you :)

Comment: and its UIViewController by the way :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `ViewController` is a `UIViewController`, instead of making the table view the main view (which will be resized for you), simply add the table view.

Replace:

```
self.view = tableView;
```

with:

```
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Now the table view will keep the frame that you set.

Since you want the table view down the left side, and presumably to fill the height, you really should do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    NSArray *first = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first", @"second", @"third", nil];
    NSArray *second = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fourth", @"fifth", @"sixth", nil];

    self.sections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first, second, nil];

    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];

    [tableView reloadData]; // don't reload until it's added and the data is ready
}
```